# Delete sources after installing driver

Tags: drivers, sound, lubuntu

I recently installed lubuntu in my ASUS laptop, as the sound was dead, I installed the realtek official drivers.

My mistake (I think) was that I installed the drivers from the "Downloads" folder with the traditional flow: `./configure -> make -> make install`

Now Im afraid that if I delete that folder sound will stop working again.

Is it safe to delete this folder (I don't want it to live on the Downloads folder) what would be the Constituencies?